# redux observable map not invoked

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable

I have this code, and failing to understand why I am not getting inside the map function (where I have the comment "I AM NEVER GETTING TO THIS PART OF THE CODE"):

```
export const fiveCPMonitoringLoadEpic = (action$, store) =>
action$
    .ofType(
        FIVE_CP_MONITORING_ACTION_TYPES.LOAD_FIVE_CP_MONITORING_DATA_STARTED
    )
    .debounceTime(250)
    .switchMap(action => {
        const params = action.params;
        const siteId = { params };

        // getting site's EDC accounts (observable):
        const siteEdcAccount$ = getSiteEDCAccountsObservable(params);
        const result$ = siteEdcAccount$.map(edcResponse => {
            // getting here - all good so far.
            const edcAccount = edcResponse[0];
            // creating another observable (from promise - nothing special)
            const fiveCPMonitoringEvent$ = getFiveCPAndTransmissionEventsObservable(
                {
                    ...params,
                    edcAccountId: edcAccount.utilityAccountNumber
                }
            );

            fiveCPMonitoringEvent$.subscribe(x => {
                // this is working... I am getting to this part of the code
                // --------------------------------------------------------
                console.log(x);
                console.log('I am getting this printed out as expected');
            });

            return fiveCPMonitoringEvent$.map(events => {
                // I NEVER GET TO THIS PART!!!!!
                // -----------------------------
                console.log('----- forecast-----');
                // according to response - request the prediction (from the event start time if ACTIVE event exists, or from current time if no active event)
                const activeEvent = DrEventUtils.getActiveEvent(events);
                if (activeEvent) {
                    // get event start time
                    const startTime = activeEvent.startTime;
                    // return getPredictionMeasurementsObservable({...params, startTime}

                    const predictions = getPredictionMock(startTime - 300);
                    return Observable.of(predictions).delay(Math.random() * 2000);
                } else {
                    // return getPredictionMeasurementsObservable({...params}

                    const predictions = getPredictionMock(
                        DateUtils.getLocalDateInUtcSeconds(new Date().getTime())
                    );
                    return Observable.of(predictions).delay(Math.random() * 2000);
                }
            });
```

can someone please shed some light here?
why when using subscribe it is working, but when using map on the observable it is not?
isn't map suppose to be invoked every time the observable fires?

Thanks,
Jim.

Answer (score 0):

Until you subscribe to your observable, it is cold and does not emit values. Once you subscribe to it, the map will be invoked. This is a feature of rxjs meant to avoid operations that make no change (= no cunsumer uses the values). There are numerous blog posts on the subject, search 'cold vs hot obserables' on google

Comment: but in redux observable - the middleware is taking care for the subscription.. I am missing something silly here probably.
why am I getting to the "// getting here - all good so far." without subscribing to anything?!